# How do I run a module written for NodeJS v6 LTS ES2015 in Meteor 1.4.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

I understand that Meteor comes with NodeJS bundled as a dependency, but I have a module written in ES6 with a default argument value declared in one of the Class methods. It's currently erring using Meteor v1.4.3.2 like so:

```
(STDERR) packages/modules.js:374
(STDERR)   constructor(options={format:'.json'}) {
(STDERR)                      ^
(STDERR)
(STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

1. Do I need to rewrite the module to *NOT* use the default argument?
2. OR... is there a way to force Meteor to run Node v6.x?
3. OR... is there a fork of a development version of Meteor that I may use for my project?
4. OR... should I introduce a module dependency to properly build the module sources for any version of Node?

**EDIT**: Someone asked for output of `node -v`. I'm definitely running node v6.10.0

```
$ > node -v
v6.10.0
```

I'm also covering the module with chai tests that run and pass the build locally using NodeJS v6.10.0 when I run `npm test` inside the module directory. The module is a local package I'm developing concurrently. It was installed in meteor using `npm install /path/to/module`.

**EDIT 2**: Unfortunately running `meteor add ecmascript` didn't do the trick. This is a custom NPM module written specifically for Node v6+. Meteor is not using Node v6, but 4.8 rather.

```
$ > meteor node --version
v4.8.0
```

It's clear that while node v4.8 supports a lot of the ES6 functionality, it does not support default function params. See: http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-default-function-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Use `imports` modules with `ecmascript` in Meteor**

Just make sure you install the [`ecmascript`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/ecmascript.html) package and use the [`imports`](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) folder structure and you should be good to go.  The `ecmascript` package definitely supports es6 parameters.  The below is from the meteor docs.

> Default expressions for function parameters, evaluated whenever the parameter is undefined, ...rest parameters for capturing remaining arguments without using the arguments object:

You can add it like this.

```
$ meteor add ecmascript
```

**2. Use `babel` to transpile the external ES6 module - *BEST Solution***

For using your npm module, you have to add something like [es6-default-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-default-params) or [babel](https://babeljs.io) to your package (the npm module...not the meteor project) so that your es6 is transpiled down to something that can be used.  This is the practice for publishing a build that can be used by any node version (eg. You don't want to require someone to target a specific node version to use your package).

Assuming you have a `package.json` inside the module. i.e. you've run `npm init` in your `/path/to/module`.

```
$ cd path/to/package
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

Create appropriate `src` and `lib` folders for two sets of sources.

```
$ mkdir src // for ES6/ES2015 sources
$ mkdir lib // for ES5 transpiled sources
```

Then edit `package.json` with a build command. This tells babel where to find the source (`src`), a preset to transpile with (`es2015`), and where to output the ES5 sources (`lib`).

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d lib --presets=es2015"
},
"main": "./lib/mymodule.js",
...
```

*NOTE a couple additional important points:*

- If you're using `git` to manage sources, add a `.gitignore` file to ignore the `./lib/` directory.
- If you're considering publishing your module to npm, add an `.npmignore` file that ignores the `./src/` directory. *If you publish with `.gitignore` alone, npm will use the `.gitignore` and omit your `/lib`!*

This information is a hybrid of the [babel cli examples](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) and [Alex Booker's babel guide](https://booker.codes/how-to-build-and-publish-es6-npm-modules-today-with-babel/).

**3. Use `meteor build` to control the Meteor build - *LAST DITCH EFFORT***

Also, I'm not sure you can upgrade the node version bundled with meteor, but you can always build your app and run in a different node version.  Use the [`meteor build`](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild) command. Then follow the directions in the built project folder.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't crack the nut here. See my EDIT 2.